# How to replace comments with /*xyx*/ from unix file?

Tags: unix, replace, sed, awk, comments

I have a file like

```
record
    decimal(10) roll_no /*DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL*/;
    string(25) name /*STRING(25) NOT NULL*/;
    decimal(3) marks = NULL /*DECIMAL(3) NULL*/;
end
```

and I want it as

```
record
    decimal(10) roll_no;
    string(25) name;
    decimal(3) marks = NULL;
end
```

Can you guys help?

I tried with awk and sed but ihad to do some manual changes at the end to get it perfect.

Comment: Rather than say "I tried but it didn't work", please **show us what you tried** and then **describe exactly what didn't work**.  That way we aren't writing the whole thing from scratch for you, and you get to learn what your mistake was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is sure that this are-one-line only comments you can use this:

```
sed 's~/\*.*\*/~~'
```

Comment: @RohanHodarkar You can thank by clicking the checkmark against any answer that helped you the most.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks :) I usually add the `g` even if it is not required, like in this case. Before deciding this I've too often forgotten it :).. But will remove here, it might be misleading

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do

```
awk '{sub(/ \/.*\//,x)}8' file
record
    decimal(10) roll_no;
    string(25) name;
    decimal(3) marks = NULL;
end
```

It replace from `/` to `/` with nothing.

Another version

```
awk -F" */" '{print $1";"}' file
record;
    decimal(10) roll_no;
    string(25) name;
    decimal(3) marks = NULL;
end;
```

Another one

```
awk -F" */" '{$0=$1";"}8' file
```

Comment: That's a `sed` task (imo). Of course it can be done also with `awk` or even with VisualBasic :)

Comment: No, I meant it should be done with `sed`. As a guideline (this is from the Sed/Awk O'reilly) : Use `sed` for editing tasks

Comment: As you write `a guideline`. No problem using `awk`.  Not all do know `sed` or may prefer `awk` etc

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I just wanted to point this out, as I really apprecitated that sentence from the O'reilly. Often the borders between `sed` and `awk` are blurry, I think this is a good example for a typical sed task

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sed command which can handle if there are not one-line only comments:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s~/\*[^*/]*\*/~~g' file
```

#### Explanation

- `':a;$!{N;ba}` read the whole file into pattern
- `s~/\*[^*/]*\*/~~g` replace any contents between /* and */